# Installing libXp on Loki

Tags: release-loki

I have installed matlab on my system. When I try to run Matlab I get this error -

```
/usr/local/bin/matlab: 1: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/bin/util/oscheck.sh:/lib64/libc.so.6: not found
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried installing libXp using

```
sudo apt-get install libXp.so.6
```

Which gave me these errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package libXp.so.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libXp.so.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXp.so.6'
```

Also tried

```
apt-get install libXp6
```

With this error

```
E: Unable to locate package libXp6
```

How do I solve this?

My architecture is x86_64

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in the repo anymore. you can [download](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/vivid/main/base/libxp6) the old .deb and install that.

To install in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i name_of_deb.deb
```